# Reusable Fusion Clip with Sound in Davinci Resolve

Tags: animation, davinci-resolve, rendering, fusion

I have created a fusion clip in Resolve 16 which displays a logo. On my timeline I also have a sound clip to go with the animation. Those are the only two clips in my project.

Now what I would like to make this reusable. In a perfect world as a mov file with an alpha channel which I can just slap onto any timeline in any project.

I tried rendering (individual clips) with the Grass Valley codec so that I can export the alpha channel but the resulting mov has no audio and the quality of the logo is real bad. When I render it using H.264 I have a black background but the quality of the logo is as I would expect and the sound is there too.

So how do I go about making Logo Animation + Sound reusable? I should say that I'm fairly new to Resolve.

Edit: In the screenshots you can see the animation looking good in the fusion page. In the color page it looks good when played. When stopped artefacts are showing. After connecting to an alpha channel the artefacts become real bad.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lasso both of them, right-click, and create a new compound clip. You could store this compound clip within a power bin, and it would be available for re-use in future projects. Or, you could write out a proRes 4444 file to your desktop and import into new projects whenever you need to (has to be 4444 at least to support transparency. If you use a different codec, be sure it does too; common ones like h.264 do not). In either case, if you have trouble with an alpha channel not showing up, you need to go into the color page, right click on the background of the node viewer and select “add alpha output”, then wire the new blue triangle output to whichever node you’re trying to get transparency from. BMD have made this step less necessary in some situations, and try to automatically display transparency when appropriate, but you’ll still encounter black sometimes, and if you do, that’s where you fix it. Oh, and when you say “render individual clips,” don’t use the render individual clips button n the deliver page. It’s for round-tripping to other software, it won’t export single clips like you see them on the timeline. To do that, you can right-click on the clip thumbnail in the deliver page and select “render this clip” from the drop down to set the in and out points to a single clip. The results are very different.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I tried creating a compound clip and storing it in the power bin but DR does not allow compound clips to be stored in power bins.  As for the second approach: How do I export to proRes 4444? I can't find it in my list of codecs.

Comment: I think prores is only on mac.  I saw a recent headline about windows adding prores RAW, but I'm not sure of the details.  Anyway, avid DNx is what windows users typically use instead, though I'm not sure which variants support transparency.

Comment: Really strange about the error message with the power bins.  That's what I get for posting an answer without being in front of my computer.  Sorry about that.  The weird thing though is that even though it says it doesn't accept fusion files, it does.  If  you drag in a plain fusion clip without first compounding it, it doesn't give that error.

Comment: There are a couple of other things that might give you bad looking edges on things with transparency from the fusion page.  Some of them are resolve bugs, some of them user error, my general advice is to avoid ACES and RCM until the bugs are fully sorted out, and to make sure you're doing premultiplication correctly in fusion.  Premultiplication errors look like too dark or too light antialiasing; the ACES bug looks like too blocky/no antialiasing.

Comment: Thanks again, Json! Since I need to have the sound go with the animation storing only the animation in a power bin won't solve my problem. I figured now that I if I add an alpha channel in the coloring page, the clip looks already ugly. There is some white noise all around the animation. Removing the alpha channel connection removes the noise again. I try to compile some screenshots and add them to my post.

Comment: Once we get the artifacts fixed, you can work around the power bin issue by exporting the thing with sound, then save the export in a power bin.  I'll re-write my answer once we figure out what's really going on.  Your most recent edit, saying that you don't see artifacts while playing leads me to believe you might have an issue with caching.  The playback used by the cache can be a different format than what you see when the image is still.  It might look fine when you export.  You might try deleting render cache in playback menu & switching to playback->render cache->none.

Comment: What's the source of the MhalaTV Node?  Is it a .png that you brought in through the media pool?  It could be compression artifacts which are becoming amplified by incorrect colorspace or gamma settings in mediain and/or mediaout nodes, or by the project color settings.

Comment: It is indeed a tiny png file. But the artefacts occur even over the text node. And while the png is animated (rotation) it doesn't change its position.

Comment: I'm still playing around here and had a little success: In the fusion page I had a background node (transparent) which I had used to "fade out" the entire animation. After removing that node and the merger for it I now can export using dnxhr and there are no artefacts. But the result is a black background instead of a transparent video eventhough i connected the alpha output and selected export alpha in the delivery page.

Comment: IDK about windows players, but Mac quicktime player will show transparent as black, so it could be your player.  In resolve, you can right-click on the export in the queue, and choose "reveal in media storage" and drag the export back into your project.  Layer that over something else like a colored background or another piece of video to check alpha.  There's easier ways, depending on your setup, but that's the easiest thing I can think of which only depends on resolve.  On mac, quickview in finder works.

Comment: If it really is black, check the outputs on the color page again.  There should be a blue triangle alpha output wired up.

Comment: After a lot of back and forth I finally got it working. You were right I did not have the triangle connected. So it all works, but the rays don't . I don't know what's going on there but everything looks good except the light rays. I removed them. I'm a happy man now. Thank you so much for your help. I learned a lot through it!